# SSO concern - server client communication

Tags: facebook-graph-api, single-sign-on

I want to get your opinion on a security concern regarding Facebook SSO (Or any SSO provider, for that matter).

When a user preforms FB SSO on the mobile and by that performs a sign-in to our app, we pass the token received from FB mobile app to our server, and the server preforms a request to FB to authenticate that the token is valid, and this is not a stolen request.

This is done only for the first time. Theoretically, on every call to our server from now on, we still need to call FB server and keep authenticating the token, as Facebook is our identity server. This obviously not ideal, since every request to our server can not be synchronized with FB server request constantly, performance-wise and for many other reasons.

However, from a security point of view, although all requests are SSL'd, our server does not know that this user token is still valid, and the only way for it to make sure, it to call FB server. (A good example for this is user doing SSO and then removed the app on FB settings.)

What are your thoughts on this issue?